# Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css on Cpanel server

Tags: cpanel, manifest, vite

Laravel Jetstream Livewire Vite Cpanel Deployment
My SetUp:

Laravel: v9.22.1
PHP: v8.1.8

Everything works perfectly on local enviorement but when I deploy the app on Cpanel I get this error:

```
Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.
```

I think is something related with Vite because if I dont run npm run build in my local it shows the same error:

```
Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.
```

I

Answer (score 0):

In my chase this problem was caused because in my manifest inside the build folder I had this error :

![problem][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jAVk.png

Correcting the \ to /

```
{
  "resources/js/app.js": {
    "file": "assets/app.ab93cf8a.js",
    "src": "resources/js/app.js",
    "isEntry": true
  },
  "resources/css/app.css": {
    "file": "assets/app.9fa9f508.css",
    "src": "resources/css/app.css"
  }
}
```

fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me was:
When i used in view

```
@vite(['resources/scss/style.scss'])
```

I had to add in vite.config.js corresponding path

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(
{
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/admin/scss/style.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```